# Get Shipping Method Title in Woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I want to retrieve the title of the shipping method on the cart page. Currently I am using

```
wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method );
```

but that returns the shipping title along with the shipping rate

```
Flat Rate: $100.00
```

I just want the "Flat Rate". I have been looking into get_method_title and get_title but not sure if they do what I need to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the label from the [`WC_Shipping_Rate`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Rate.html) object `$method` you will have to replace:

```
wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method );
```

by simply:

```
$label = $method->get_label();
echo $label;
```